# Confused about getting Scala to run in IntelliJ? Import errors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, import

I am trying to run a simple scala program in IntelliJ.

My build.sbt looks like this:

```
name := "UseThis"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"
```

And my import code looks like this:

```
package WorkWork.FriendsByAge

import com.sun.glass.ui.Window.Level
import com.sun.istack.internal.logging.Logger
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j._
```

I don't get why the import fails. It tells me the dependency failed to load or wasn't found, but I put the line in the build.sbt as required. Is there some other step I need to have done? I've installed spark. Is it the version note at the end of the build line? I don't even know how to check what version I have of spark. 
I'm trying to teach myself Scala (not a noob though, I know Python, R, various flavors of SQL, C#) but my word even setting it up is nigh on impossible, and apparently getting it to even run is too. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check that your version of spark works with 2.12.4? Is there even a spark in the wild out there that supports 2.12.4 already? They usually lag behind a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this page here: [Maven Central (Apache Spark core)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core)

Unless you have set up some other repositories, the dependencies that are going to be loaded by `sbt` usually come from there.

There is a `version` column with numbers like `2.2.1`, then there comes a `scala` column with numbers like `2.11`, `2.10`. In order for spark and scala to work together, you have to pick a valid combination from this table.

As of 28.Feb 2018, there are no versions of Spark that work with scala 2.12.4. The latest version of scala for which `1.2.0` works is `2.11`. So, you will probably want to set scala version to `2.11`.

Also note that the `%%` syntax in your SBT in

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"
```

will automatically append the suffix `_2.12` to the artifact-id-part. Since there is no `spark-core_2.12`, it cannot resolve the dependency, and you can't import anything in your code.

By the way: there was a big difference between spark 1.2 and spark 1.3, and then there was again a big difference between 1.x and 2.x. Does it really have to be 1.2?

Comment: I realized I was screwing that up too yeah :P man I hate scala but big data requires what it requires I guess

Comment: Y U hate scala, maaan! xD You don't even have a golden haskell badge yet, you're not allowed to hate scala until then ;)

Comment: Minor correction: the suffix is `_2.12`, not `_2_12`, and appended to the `spark-core` part, not to `org.apache.spark`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, indeed, why in the world would it append a scala version to the groupID... No Idea why I wrote that^^ Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Its because Spark 1.2 is not available for Scala 2.12

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core

Comment: a little bit explanation would be fruitful :)